# Attribute labels to scored items [function]

Tags: r, list, function, if-statement

I don't know if the subject has already been find but here my problem :
I have a dataset from behaviors personality items scored from 1 to 8 and I would like to convert each scored according a range (e.g. 1-2 = Rare ; 3-5 = Occasionally ; 6-8 = Frequent).
I succeed to create new columns and put labels in it but I don't understand why I have same repetition in others columns :

```
Beh_data[,c(2,3,4,32,33,34)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4mL3.png)

You can see that columns with "_class" had the same outputs, and there are mistakes about correct match between labels and scores (e.g. row4 -- 8 put as Occasionally)

Here the function code :

```
  l = unlist(names(Beh_data[,2:28]))
  for (j in 1:length(l)) {
    cl[j] = list(paste(l[j],"class",sep="_"))
    for (k in 1:length(cl)) {
      Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ] <- cl[[k]]
      for(i in 1:nrow(Beh_data)){
        Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ][i] <-ifelse(Beh_data[,l[j] ][i]<3, "Rare", Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ][i])
        Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ][i] <-ifelse(Beh_data[,l[j] ][i]>2 & Beh_data[,l[j] ][i]<6, "Occasionally", Beh_data[,cl[[k] ] ][i])
        Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ][i] <-ifelse(Beh_data[,l[j] ][i]>5, "Frequent", Beh_data[,cl[[k]] ][i])
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to see if it's could from a wrong annotation as cl[[k]] ] or something like this but it steels doesn't work
Do you have any ideas please ?

Comment: Thank you for having editing correctly the post
Did I make something wrong ?
>   Beh_data |> mutate(across(aff_sum:qui_sum), ~case_when(. >= 6 ~ "Frequent", . >= 3 ~ "Occasionally", TRUE ~ "Rare"), .names = "{.col}_class:"))
Error: unexpected ')' in "  Beh_data |> mutate(across(aff_sum:qui_sum), ~case_when(. >= 6 ~ "Frequent", . >= 3 ~ "Occasionally", TRUE ~ "Rare"), .names = "{.col}_class:"))"
Thank you

Comment: I had a typo `)`, see correction in answer. For future reference, it is a help for potential answerers if you can include some example data, such as would be created by running `dput(Beh_data[1:6,c(2,3,4,32,33,34)])` and pasting the code that produces into the body of your question. That would have allowed me to verify my answer's syntax, but I think I fixed it now.

Comment: Yes indeed, it works wonderfully, Thank you so much !!!!
I take my hat off to you

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a `dplyr` solution, I think its `across` and `case_when` functions are helpful here. It should also run faster since it's vectorized. This will create new columns like `aff_sum_class` which use the categorization you've specified.

```
library(dplyr)
Beh_data |> 
  mutate(across(aff_sum:qui_sum, 
                ~case_when(. >= 6 ~ "Frequent", 
                           . >= 3 ~ "Occasionally", 
                           TRUE ~ "Rare"), 
                .names = "{.col}_class"))
```

Comment: I am open to dplyr and I think I will learn it asap seing how it's so usefull !! Thank you again